# Authenticate / Authorize customer's applications to use my API

Tags: api, authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization, access-token

I am a bit puzzled after reading too much documentation about authorization authentication.

Our **customers are companies** that consume our APIs with their (server side) programs.

I want to automate api access-tokens delivery. (New contract - > New customer on our identity server -> access to "application portal" to let them create applications linked to their company and API keys generations).

I've always used custom solutions with custom code for that (ie mods of simple services like https://github.com/ISI-nc/autentigo).

I do not see how commercial solutions / standards can answer this requirement today. I would love not to implement something myself, is there any standard that covers :

- identification of customer's company (and not single individuals from my customer's company),
- identification of customer's applications,
- self service to allow customer's applications administrator to declare applications and generate access tokens,
- check permissions and authorise access tokens based on customer's access permissions.

This is not my usual technical narrow stack overflow question and may be too broad. If this is the case, please help me refine the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your use case sounds similar to how Open Banking works, to enable dynamic business:

- Bank provides an API
- Authorized merchant companies can onboard at any time and create one or more clients in the bank authorization server, that can connect to the API
- Users buy things using merchant client applications, which use bank access tokens to manage payments

For this to work, [OAuth dynamic client registration](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc7591/) is used, which is a behaviour implemented by authorization servers. Also some kind of trust is needed, which is typically managed in Open Banking by each merchant receiving a distinct client certificate from an authority.

**DATA OWNER ISSUES TOKENS**

Whether you use DCR depends on how dynamic you want go be, though the pattern is useful to know about. This type of solution enables customers to get your access tokens to call your APIs. Usually in cross organization solutions, clients are APIs from the client organization.

To protect its own data, each customer is likely to also have its own client applications and API security, in case that isn't clear. This allows them to define their own scopes and claims to be issued to access tokens. Typically they will use their own identity and access management system for this.